# I think I might be missing the Tenacious badge

Tags: support, badges, zero-score-badges

The explanation for the Tenacious badge says:

> - Have at least five accepted answers
>     with a score of zero, and have those
>     zero-score accepted answers account
>     for at least 20% of all your accepted
>     answers
> - Only accepted answers at least ten
>     days old are considered
> - Community Wiki answers, deleted
>     answers, and self-accepted answers are
>     not included in any calculations

If I count correctly on [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310001/nailuj#qpage_1-apage_1-qsort_votes-asort_recent), I have 19 accepted answers in total. Out of these, 5 are 0-score not-self-accepted answers (and no CW either). The most recent of these 5 were answered on November the 15th at 13:10, which is twelve days ago.

Are my maths completely wrong, or does it just take some time for this badge to be awarded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirement that seems to be in question is the `5` count. When you leave out your self-accepted asnwers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802849/problem-installing-maven-plugin-m2eclipse-in-eclipse-galileo/2803664#2803664), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700179/performance-issue-with-asp-net-page-with-many-hundreds-of-collapsiblepanelexten/2735771#2735771) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951274/noclassdeffounderror-when-trying-to-unit-test-json-parsing-in-android/3972592#3972592)).

This means you have:

- 19 accepted answers, but only 16 non-self-accepted
- 7 accepted answers with a 0 score, but only 5 non-self-accepted

This means your percentage is 5/16 or 31.25% so you're good there, but the difference in your question and the badge description is the wording (emphasis mine):

> - Have **at least five** accepted answers with a score of zero, and have those zero-score accepted answers account for at least 20% of all your accepted answers

Whereas [the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious) says (again, emphasis mine):

> Zero score accepted answers: **more than 5** and 20% of total.

So it appears to be behaving like the description says, meaning you need a 6<sup>th</sup> answer to qualify. I think the problem is just that [the description here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-is-each-badge#68258) is wrong, the badge page is (or at lest seems to be) correct.

Comment: Thanks Nick, didn't notice that minor difference. I guess this is also the same for Unsung Hero then, as it says *more than 10 and 25% of total* on the badge description, but *at least ten accepted answers with a score of zero* in the FAQ post. Seems like you're correct, but waiting for some moderator to confirm :)

Comment: "more than" is the correct version; I've fixed the description in the badge list question